# How can i avoid or disable a textBox so the user wont be able to type anything inside?

Tags: c#, winforms

I dont want to disable or make the textBox read only.
Since it will fill the textBox in gray color.

I want just to make that if the user will try to type anything inside the textBox nothing will happen.

So i tried this :

```
textBox1.Enabled = false;
```

But i want to make that the user wont be able to type anything inside not to lock or make it read only properties.

I tried this example :

```
private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
```

It's working for chars/strings but i still able to enter digits(numbers).
How can i also avoid prevent from the user to also enter numbers ?

Comment: Don't know if you can but, can you make it read only and change the background color? Haven't tried to do this so don't necessarily know if it works.

Comment: If you are disabling it then why not let the user know about it :( , why should they play around the textbox to finally realize that it doesn't let them type in phewww

Comment: `textBox1.ReadOnly = true`?

Comment: Winforms i guess. And ReadOnly true make it gray inside. Which is not what i needed.

Comment: I've never seen ReadOnly make a textbox gray...

Comment: Disabling a text box and not making it *look* disabled is a UI Blooper.  Pity the poor user that has no idea why it doesn't work, banging on the mouse and keyboard fruitlessly.  You can get unsubtle about it by using its DrawToBitmap() method.  Assign it to a PictureBox.Image property that has the same size and location as the textbox and is on top.  The user won't have any clue that it is actually a bitmap and not a control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try either:

```
textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
```

or you could also try

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your textbox as readonly, then its forecolor to black and its background color to white.